# Find Max Value Index Match Match

Tags: excel, indexing, google-sheets, max, match

I am collecting athletics scores from students, as shown in this example:

[image: Athletic Scores]

The students may have more than one attempt over a number of weeks.

How do I summarise the maximum score in every event for each student?

For example:
Mark's best score for Long Jump is 2.5m and best javelin throw is 23m.

Currently I am using index match match to collate the scores but this is not showing the maximum values.

```
=index(A1:C8,match(A11,A1:A8,0),match(B10,A1:C1,0))
```

Comment: What language/tool is this in? Excel? If so, add that tag as well please. Also describe what the result is you get with your current attempt.

Comment: Currently the result is the first value rather than the maximum value.  Therefore in my example, my formula returns Mark's score for high jump as 2.00 whereas his best was 2.5

Comment: I am getting closer.  With max added to the formula:  =index(max(A1:C8,match(A11,A1:A8,0),match(B10,A1:C1,0))  This returns the maximum value in the whole table rather than the relevant column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an array formula to do this which means when entering the formula you will need to press `Ctrl` + `Enter`. The formula will then be surrounded by `{` and `}`. You cannot add the `{}` manually.

Try this formula for Long Jump:

```
={MAX((B$2:B$7)*($A$2:$A$7="Mark"))}
```

And this for Javelin:

```
={MAX((C$2:C$7)*($A$2:$A$7="Mark"))}
```

Comment: Thank you Jordan.  I have managed to adjust your formula so it collates the max value on data entered on a google form and it works perfectly.